# Read file to blob and display in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, blob

So I'm trying to create a basic prototype of a functionality. Essentially the end goal is to receive a Base64 encoded string and a support mime type and generate the file and serve it up from a HTML 5 APP. For now I'm working on simple getting a file, turning it into a Blob, and then displaying it, all from memory.

```
   var blobfile = atob(base64);
   window.blobFromBlob = new Blob([binaryString], {
     type: MIMEType
   });
   window.blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(window.blobFromBlob);
   var a = "<a href=\"" + window.blobURL + "\">Binary Blob Link</a>";
   document.getElementById('byte_content').innerHTML = a;
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajwhiteway/nuvc120h/) to show what I'm having trouble with. When I put, say a JPEG, into it and then try to serve it up the img tags show corrupt images. The Base64 blob I never expect to work, but the Binary blob and blob from base 64 I do expect to work.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

NOTE: I managed to get the binary one to display by changing from `readAsBinaryString` to `readAsArrayBuffer`

NOTE 2: I'm beginning to suspect it has something to do with `atob` and `btoa`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So incase anyone else stumbles upon this and finds it useful I was able to solve this with help from [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript). The solution involves leaving `readAsBinaryString` as the file reading method. Create the Base64 string with `btoa` and then use `b64toBlob` function found in the [mentioned stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript).

Here is the adjusted JSFiddle to show how I got it to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ajwhiteway/vstj3bcm/1/